Synchronize multiple digital signals sampled at different frequencies
I am recording videos using multiple raspberry pis. Some videos are sampled at 30Hz, others at 90Hz and they start at different times. On each frame I also record digital inputs for offline synchronization. These inputs are saved at frame writing and are given by the state of GPIO pins integrated in the raspberry pis. I send these pulses from another system that can have any arbitrary frequency (>> videos FPS). Right now I send a single pulse and align the rising edge of the pulse. My problem is that with this solution the offset between 2 systems can be up to 33ms. Ideally I would like to synchronize these videos within 1ms of each other. Intuitively it feels like I could achieve that, for instance if I send a square wave with a period of 32ms, then I could find when an entire period fell within 2 frames of a 30Hz video. But I was wondering if there is a more elegant/efficient way to do this.
I have tried simulating a 1/f signal at 1000Hz, discretely sampled at 30Hz. Then upsample it back to 1000Hz and cross-correlate it (example below). But I always find a delay (perhaps unsurprisingly) that is a multiple of my sampling period (33.3ms).

I have seen similar questions such as this one for analog signals:
Phase difference between signals sampled at different frequencies. But it's not clear to me how I could generalize this for digital signals.
Ideally, this signal would need to be relatively short (e.g. 1sec) to allow synchronization at every recording and I find a solution that would work for both the videos at 30Hz and those at 90Hz. Finally the clocks of each system are slightly different but if I measure the delay at the beginning and end of every recording, I can assume that the clock drift is constant over time.

Please edit your question for clarity.  How are your digital inputs recorded?  Are they going through the video path, injected into the digital stream after recording, put onto the audio track, or what?  How closely do you need the video to synchronize?  Have you looked for cameras that can be synchronized externally?  Why aren't you doing this?

The inputs come from the GPIO pins of the rPis. They are measured at frame writing time and stored in a separate css file. I did not explain that since it is not really relevant to the question at hand, which is purely mathematical.

The reason why I am doing this and why this way are not super relevant either. I have meany reasons to use raspberry pi including, but not limited to, size and price. I am fully aware that some cameras can be synchronised externally. It is just not an option here.

if you sample at 1kHz and get the top graph, and then sample same signal at 30Hz and get the graph in the middle, then there's some alias, or sampling frequency, not the alignment. has not been chosen correctly. Those glitches in top graph, missing in middle graph mean either 30Hz is way too low or the ADC changes level when it shouldn't.
